# Android: ViewPager - adding Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to add a ViewPager, but I am am having problems adding new fragments.  I followed a tutorial to create it where the on each swipe the SAME fragment was used with only a TextView in the fragment changing changing.

The fragment that works is called MyFragment. ( I don't know why this works and the others don't.

I don't want to use this fragment as I have different fragments that I have already made (that work fine).   I want to add for example a fragment called ReminderFragment

I tried adding a switch and case to the getItem() method,  but I get an error saying: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from *name of fragment* to Fragment".

This is the code of my FragmentActivity - it holds the FragmentPagerAdapter inside it (I don't know if this is a good way or not):

```
// Removed imports, package name

public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;  
   private ViewPager pager; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_activity);  // Sets the layout to an xml which includes a viewpager

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();  

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); 

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(1); 
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer()); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
        } else if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
        else if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 2){
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){ 
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>(); 
         // I don't know how to change this to work with my fragments
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Page 0"));  // MyFragment is the fragment I don't need, but it is the only fragment that works!
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Page 1"));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Page 2"));

        return fList;
    }

    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  // Sets what MyPagerAdapter is
        private List<Fragment> fragments; // Defines a list of fragments called fragments

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) { // Sets what is inside the MyPagerAdapter
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    //    return this.fragments.get(index);
        switch (index){
        case 0: return new ReminderFragment(); // This is where I get errors
        case 1: return new QuickNoteFragment();
        }


            } 

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           return this.fragments.size();
          }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the ReminderFragment.  This does not work as I get the error above

```
// Removed stuff

public class ReminderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{




public static final String ARG_nOTERACTIVITY_NUMBER = "noter_activity";

// Removed stuff


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View remView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_nOTERACTIVITY_NUMBER);
    String noter_activity = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.noter_array)[i];

    // Removed stuff

    getActivity().setTitle(noter_activity); // For navigation drawer(?)
    return remView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.***: // Does stuff



        case R.id.***:
             break;
                 }
    }
}



public static Fragment newInstance() {  // Is this necessary
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ReminderFragment remFrag = new ReminderFragment();
    return remFrag;
}
}
```

I know there are two methods of adding the fragments here - I just trying to show what I have tried :-).  I am very confused!

Thank you

Comment: newInstance() pattern is only necessary if you use parameters when you create you fragment. Then you have to add them to your bundle.

Comment: @Warpzit So how do I add the fragments without useing the newInstante()?

Comment: heh, "new WhateverFragment" like your already doing in the sample... but if you need to put a parameter of some kind you use newInstance pattern and put the parameters in the bundle.

Comment: did u add import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; If you not, just add and try it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks that you imported Fragments from the support package in all the class. The import should be `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment` (if you are targeting API level 11) in all the class

Comment: If I change all the fragments to android.app.Fragment, I get an error at the: The "Fragment" says add return type...   @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return this.fragments.get(index);
        switch (index){
        case 0: return new ReminderFragment();
        case 1: return new QuickNoteFragment();
        }

Comment: make sure that all imports are consistent. Means you should import android.support.v4.app.Fragment in every class that use Fragments

Comment: If I do that, then I get an error in my NavigationDrawer. So I tried changing them all to import android.app.Fragment, but I still get the error on the "Fragment" I showed above, and on " pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);"

Comment: what error do you get in your NavigatioDrawer ? You can not use getSupportFragmentManager if you import android.app.Fragment, you have to use getFragmentManager instead

Comment: If everything uses the support Fragment bits then there are no errors anywhere except when I use getSupportFragmentManager in the navigation drawer. ( I think I will try to stick to using the support fragment bits for future reference)

Comment: Sorry - I was mistaken with what  wrote in this comment!

Comment: OK - I have removed the errors in the NavigationDrawer, so the app loads fine (I had to extend FragmentActivity).  But now, when I open the ViewPager Activity, I just get a blank screen

Comment: blank screen could be anything . Start checking your layout

Comment: The layouts are fine (I think) - the ViewPager layout only contains the ViewPager, and the layout of the Fragments are definitely fine as I have used them before.  Is the problem that I've got two methods of add the fragments? If so how do just use one?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! - I never thought the different imports would make a problem :-)  I think I will have to start the ViewPager again from scratch and make sure I get it right.